# Simple way to model JSon in C++

Tags: c++, json, boost-variant, boost-propertytree

I need to model a JSon in C++. Firstly I thought about:

```
boost::property_tree
```

But unfortunately - it does not care about JSon types. Integers are represented as strings - and it is not an option.

The second idea would be:

```
boost::variant with recursive_wrapper
```

Which looks quite promising.

What kind of approach could you recommend? Do you know better approaches? It looks like a common problem, so there have to be a lot of well tested solutions.

I'm unfamiliar with C++ JSon libraries. If you could recommend any - I would be grateful as well.

Comment: What about using json libraries?..

Comment: Are you sure? In boost::property_tree page I can read "In addition, the library provides parsers and generators for a number of data formats that can be represented by such a tree, including XML, INI, and JSON."

Comment: You may also consider using Qt's QJson framework which is pretty good.

Comment: @Marco I would be glad to use Qt, unfortunately I cannot due to licensing issues,

Comment: @Dejwi I am sure you know what you are doing, but just in case you missed it Qt licensing has many options including LGPL

Answer (score 2):

For JSon you typically want to take a library. You could ofcourse write your own implementation (parser etc.) but I don't see why you would do that considering there are so many good ones freely available.

Some examples:

- https://github.com/kazuho/picojson      (Header only)
- https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson

Comment: Try https://github.com/nlohmann/json It is a header only library and pretty simple to use and provides most necessary functionalities.

Comment: boost::spirit + boost::variant = json_spirit
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20027/JSON-Spirit-A-C-JSON-Parser-Generator-Implemented